# Is it possible to include an interactive set of radio buttons inside an SVG file?

Tags: svg, radio-button, interactive

I want to create an SVG file with four buttons, one of which is lit up while the other three are darkened, and where clicking/tapping on one of the unlit buttons lights it up while darkening the previously-lit button. In regular HTML I would simply use a radio-group of `<input type="radio">` elements, but that doesn't seem to work in SVG.

The buttons don't have to do anything besides lighten/darken (there's no action to perform or form to submit). This is purely a decorative image, I just want to jazz it up with some interactivity.

Is this at all possible to achieve inside a self-contained SVG file? I know you can include JavaScript in SVGs, but I'm not super familiar with JS so I'm not sure if that's the way to go or if there's a better option.

Comment: You are writing "self-contained". Does that mean that the SVG is loaded directly in the browser without a "container" HTML page or are you embedding the SVG in HTML using `<object>` or is the SVG inline with all the HTML?

Comment: @chrwahl The SVG file will be displayed on a webpage inside an `<img>` tag, as a normal image. I don't have full control over the pages where it will be displayed, so I can't add scripts or elements outside the SVG file to manipulate it; everything must be done within the SVG file itself.

Comment: If the SVG is displayed using an img tag it is not possible to have any script interacting with the SVG either for the inside or outside. Åbn object tag would be better in that regard. Would it be possible to have a combination of SVGs in img tags and interactive HTML around them ( if that make sense)?

Comment: I'll look into whether or not it's possible to use an `<object>` tag or some external script in my particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG does not have buttons or input elements. Here is an example of how you can switch between "buttons" by adding and/or removing a class name.

```js
document.getElementById('tabs').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let svg = e.target.closest('svg');
  let btn = e.target.closest('.btn');
  if(btn){
    [...svg.querySelectorAll('.btn')].forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('on'));
    btn.classList.add('on');
    console.log(btn.id, 'was clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  fill: PeachPuff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.on {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg id="tabs" xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" viewBox="0 0 30 10">
  <rect id="btn1" class="btn" width="9" height="5" rx="1" />
  <rect id="btn2" class="btn" width="9" height="5" x="10" rx="1" />
  <rect id="btn3" class="btn" width="9" height="5" x="20" rx="1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This works almost exactly as I want, with one minor problem - clicking within the SVG file but outside all the rects turns off all the boxes and throws an error message in the console (`Uncaught TypeError: btn is null`). Can this script be modified so that clicking outside the rects does nothing (so the last selected rect remains lit instead of becoming unlit)?

Comment: @Lawton oh, I needed to test if a btn was clicked... The answer has been updated.

Comment: That does it! Thank you for your assistance.